# Footer selector error even after adding a footer class

Tags: footer

## [I have been trying to add a footer at the end of my page with the font size being 14px. I have even added a footer selector. But I'm still getting an error](https**your text**://i.stack.imgur.com/2pmHt.png)

it would be great if someone helped me out here!

Comment: I think they want you to apply the CSS directly to the footer rather than to a class assigned to the footer element. So `<footer>` and `footer {}` instead of `<footer class="footer">` and `.footer {}`. Could be wrong but worth a shot.